# Getting string from webpage in Android

Tags: android, string, html

Is possible get a String from a webpage in Android? I can see several ways to take all the html content, but is there a way to get ONLY an element?
Thanks in advance.

Solved with jsoup by executing this from onCreateView method:

```
private class Take extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String desc;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Element link = document.select("h2").first();
                String text = document.body().text();
                String linkText = link.text();   
                Log.d(linkText, linkText);
                Log.d(text, text);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, you need to get whole html parse and get the element ...

Comment: can you make an example?

Comment: yeah, sure: `some.library.HTMLDocument doc = some.library.HTMLDocument.fromUrl("http://example.com"); some.library.HTMLElement elem = doc.findElementById("xxxx");` of course the `HTMLDocument` class my be vary depending on library used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes its possible you have to use a library called **jsoup**, read more about it here http://jsoup.org/

here's an example

```
File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");

Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("a");
for (Element link : links) {
  String linkHref = link.attr("href");
  String linkText = link.text();
}
```

Comment: I'll receive my output into linkText?

Comment: its just a string name, you can use others if you want.

Comment: Almost done, one last thing: do I need a webview or the page already saved? Or I only have to change "http://example.com/"?

Comment: i have not tried it here's the api docs you can refer this http://jsoup.org/apidocs/. glad i could be of help

Comment: I think I can't set the file " input "

Comment: I can't find a way to get html page, I tried every method on stack, but they're all deprecated.